# Mask 2D array preserving shape

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have 2D numpy array something like this:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,4],
                [2,1,1],
                [1,2,3]])
```

and a boolean array:

```
boolarr = np.array([[True, True, False],
                    [False, False, True],
                    [True, True,True]])
```

Now, when I try to slice arr based on boolarr, it gives me

```
arr[boolarr]
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3])
```

But I am looking to have a 2D array output instead. The desired output is

```
[[1, 2],
 [1],
 [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Just FYI, pure Numpy arrays with varying row lengths don't exist as far as I'm aware. You could have a nested list, a Numpy array of references to lists, or a list of Numpy arrays, however.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Second that. Depending on what you want to do with it, I would either stick with Python `list` or use something as placeholders in the non-desired positions (nan)

Comment: @Tomothy32 they kinda exist. You get an array of list types because it's not possible to have continguous blocks of memory for such structures. But, they might as well be lists :)

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, I just mean with OP's wanted operation you won't get something similar to the 3x3 2D array you started with.

Comment: @Tomothy32 correct. OP, you're probably looking at an XY problem or, at the very least, creating issues for yourself here using numpy. You may be able to maintain the shape of the array if you're willing to accept something like `np.nan` at the indices you don't want (perhaps that's enough for you to carry forward to the next step of whatever calculation you're doing)

Comment: Looks like a possible use case for masked arrays.

Comment: numpy is so frustrating sometimes. things often just work, and then intuitive syntax like the op wants to use, and you end up with weird errors and 20 minutes down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option using `numpy` is to start by adding up rows in the `mask`:

```
take = boolarr.sum(axis=1)
#array([2, 1, 3])
```

Then mask the array as you do:

```
x = arr[boolarr]
#array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3])
```

And use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split the flat array according to the [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) of `take` (as the function expects the indices where to split the array):

```
np.split(x, np.cumsum(take)[:-1])
[array([1, 2]), array([1]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

---

**General solution**

```
def mask_nd(x, m):
    '''
    Mask a 2D array and preserve the
    dimension on the resulting array
    ----------
    x: np.array
       2D array on which to apply a mask
    m: np.array
        2D boolean mask  
    Returns
    -------
    List of arrays. Each array contains the
    elements from the rows in x once masked.
    If no elements in a row are selected the 
    corresponding array will be empty
    '''
    take = m.sum(axis=1)
    return np.split(x[m], np.cumsum(take)[:-1])
```

---

**Examples**

Lets have a look at some examples:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,4],
                [2,1,1],
                [1,2,3]])

boolarr = np.array([[True, True, False],
                    [False, False, False],
                    [True, True,True]])

mask_nd(arr, boolarr)
# [array([1, 2]), array([], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

Or for the following arrays:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2],
                [2,1]])

boolarr = np.array([[True, True],
                    [True, False]])

mask_nd(arr, boolarr)
# [array([1, 2]), array([2])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is not a 2D array, since each "row" has a different number of "columns". A functional non-vectorised solution is possible via [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

res = list(map(list, map(compress, arr, boolarr)))

# [[1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with `list` instead:

```
[[arr[row][col] for col in range(3) if boolarr[row][col]] for row in range(3)]
# [[1,2], [1], [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Pretty inefficient tho, on a numpy array.

Comment: @U9-Forward no less efficient than on a list, and the OP's desired output doesn't really work in NumPy

Comment: @roganjosh Okay.

Comment: On this small example this times about the same as all the rest.  The `split` one is slowest.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something as simple as a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html). You can use the mask to create an array that masks out the desired values, so that they are not affected by further operations and don't affect the results of calculations:

```
marr = np.ma.array(arr, mask=~boolarr)
```

Notice that the mask must be flipped since it's the invalid elements that are masked. The result will look like

```
masked_array(data=[
        [ 1  2 --]
        [-- --  1]
        [ 1  2  3]],
    mask=[
        [False False  True]
        [ True  True False]
        [False False False]],
    fill_value = 999999)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [183]: np.array([x[y] for x,y in zip(arr, boolarr)])
Out[183]: array([array([1, 2]), array([1]), array([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

should be competitive in speed.  (It's a little faster if we omit the outer `np.array` wrap, returning just a list of arrays.)

But realistic time tests are needed to be sure.